# AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I an reading a HDF5 file using h5py, with the following keys

```
> InputFile ='Wavenewscope_CH1.h5'
f = h5py.File(InputFile, 'r')
print f.keys()

[u'FileType', u'Frame', u'Waveforms']

> print f['Waveforms'].keys()
[u'Channel 1']
```

and this in turn has the following attributes

```
> print f['Waveforms']['Channel 1'].attrs.keys()
[u'WaveformType', u'Start', u'NumPoints', u'NumSegments', u'Count', u'XDispRange', u'XDispOrigin', u'XInc', u'XOrg', u'XUnits', u'YDispRange', u'YDispOrigin', u'YInc', u'YOrg', u'YReference', u'YUnits', u'MinBandwidth', u'MaxBandwidth', u'SavedInterpFactor', u'DispInterpFactor', u'InterpSetting', u'WavAttr', u'FFT_RBW']
```

The `NumSegments` is equal to 32005, and I expect 32005 values for the attribute `XInc`. I am trying to access the multiple values the following way (the 20th value for eg):

```
> print f['Waveforms']['Channel 1']['Channel 1 Seg20Data'].value[20]
```

However I get the error

```
'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'value'.
```

Any ideas on how to get all the values?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `f['Waveforms']['Channel 1']['Channel 1 Seg20Data']` show?  We can't explore the file for you.

Comment: Apologies. It shows<HDF5 dataset "Channel 1 Seg20Data": shape (32005,), type "<f4">

Comment: Does `f['Waveforms']['Channel 1']['Channel 1 Seg20Data'][20]` work.  It looks  like a normal dataset, which can be indexed directly.  `[:]` will for example load the whole thing into an numpy array.  `.value` is supposed to do the same, but indexing is preferred.

Comment: It appears you are using Python 2.  What version of `h5py`?

Comment: Thanks. f['Waveforms']['Channel 1']['Channel 1 Seg20Data'][:] does work for me. I can load the values in a numpy array. I have another question. I want to look at the values of the attr ('XInc'). It should have 32005 values, one for each NumSegment. However, when I print the value of f['Waveforms']['Channel 1'].attrs['XInc'], I only see a single value. Is there a way to check if 'XInc' is a float or an array of float (as I expect it to be)? Thanks again in advance.

Comment: Usually `attrs` store scalars and small arrays, while the big ones are put in `datasets`.  I'm not as familiar with accessing `attrs`, though it sound like you just have a number there, not an array.

Comment: Attributes reference page: http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/attr.html

Comment: I see. I think I was looking at the wrong attribute. print f['Waveforms']['Channel 1']['Channel 1 Seg20Data'].attrs.keys() shows me the following attrs: [u'LfdSeed', u'StartIndex', u'DataType', u'DecMode', u'PktSize', u'RawNumPts', u'ReductionAllowed', u'MemConIntlvMode', u'InfoValid', u'SegmentedTimeTag', u'SegmentedXOrg'] and print f['Waveforms']['Channel 1']['Channel 1 Seg20Data'].size shows me that indeed the size is equal to 32005. Something like f['Waveforms']['Channel 1']['Channel 1 Seg20Data']['SegmentedXOrg'].value however does not allow me to look at all the 32005 values. Any tips?

Comment: The error I get is "ValueError: Field names only allowed for compound types"

Comment: `f['Waveforms']['Channel 1']['Channel 1 Seg20Data'].attrs['SegmentedXorg']` should give the value of that `attr`.  The dataset has its values which you accessed with `[:]` or `[20]`.  The `attrs` are separate values that you access via `.attrs[name]`.  Don't confuse the two.

Comment: Keep in mind that a `.attrs` manager is a dictionary, or at least dictionary like.  In particular you can list its `keys()`, its `values()` and `items()`, as well as fetching a value by key.

Comment: I see. I understand the concept now. Thanks for the very useful discussion!